# Setting up a WebAPI, Fiddler response is an html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get a web api set up that will use RESTful services. I am following this guide.

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

I am also following this guide for setting up Entity Framework.

[Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

When I run a `Composer` in Fiddler. I get the webpage for `Home.aspx`

Here is the code for my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebServer.z_Repository;
using WebServer.z_Models;

namespace WebServer.z_Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Locations")]
    public class LocationsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        static IlocationsRepository LocationsRepo;

        public LocationsController(IlocationsRepository _repo)
        {
            if (_repo == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("_repo"); }
            LocationsRepo = _repo;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Location> GetAll()
        {
            return LocationsRepo.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the `GetAll()` and that breakpoint was never hit. This tells me that the controller isn't registered somewhere. But the guide doesn't say anything about where it should be registered.

I created a `Global.asax.cs` page even though this is not in the guide. But I am unsure of where to go from here.

Code for Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace WebServer
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet showing the response in the Fiddler
[image: Fiddler showing Home.aspx webpage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home is showing because according to the URL you showed in Fiddler:

```
GET Home.aspx/api/locations
```

it is being told to go to `Home.aspx`

You are using attribute routing but have not shown any setup for it.

Reference: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Your controller should be:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Locations")]
public class LocationsController : ApiController
{
    IlocationsRepository locationsRepo;

    public LocationsController(IlocationsRepository _repo)
    {
        if (_repo == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("_repo"); }
        this.locationsRepo = _repo;
    }

    //GET api/locations
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(""}]
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetAll()
    {
        return locationsRepo.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Your WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and in your global, include

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Pass a delegate to the Configure method.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Now in order to hit locations web api you will need to call

```
GET api/location
Host: localhost:59104
```

which works out to `http://localhost:59104/api/locations`

Comment: I'm unsure where to get the `GlobalConfiguration` to show up in intellisense. Do I need a using statement in `Global.cs`

Comment: Did you install the nuget packages for WebAPI? Any how, if you do not have the `WebApiConfig.cs` then you need to create one. Yes you will need a using statement in the Global `System.Web.Http`. You should really read the article linked in the answer.

Comment: Did everything you said. Definitely making progress, but fiddler got a 500 internal server error. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Well I'm seeing that you have DI in your ApiController but no dependency resolver. I would suggest you start looking there. Look up for `DependencyResolver` in WebApi 2

Comment: That was it. I took out the DI. And just defined a `List<Location>` put some data in it and sure enough I got them returned! Thank you for the help. Now just to figure out what I'm missing on the Entity side!!

Comment: Perhaps try one the default Web Api templates that come with VS, they have all this set-up out of the box.